# placeholder text in zend text element

Tags: php, html, zend-framework, placeholder

I am working on a Zend form application where my form contains text boxes with watermarks.

we can achieve this in HTML by the following code:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" name="q" />
```

My question is **how to add the placeholder attribute in my input-box using Zend form ?**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's already been mentioned to use:

```
$element->setAttrib('placeholder', 'Search');
```

You can also use it like this when extending Zend_Form

```
$element = $this->createElement('text', 'q', array(
           'placeholder' => 'Search',
           'label'       => 'Search'
));
```

Or inside the view using Zend_View_Helper_FormText

```
echo $this->formText('q',null, array('placeholder' => 'Search'));
```

Comment: For others like me: In Zend Expressive 3 setAttrib() is renamed to setAttribute()

Answer (score 3):

I think you can call settAttrib() on your element like this when you define elements

```
    $element->setAttrib ( 'placeholder', 'search' );
```

Answer (score 3):

On Zend_Form_Element objects you can specify attributes:

```
$element->setAttrib('placeholder', 'Search');
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an update for ZF2.
You'll have to use this in your Zend\Form\Form :

```
$this->add(
    [
        'name'    => 'q',
        'type'    => 'Text',
        'options' => [
            'label' => 'Search',
        ],
        'attributes' => [
            'placeholder' => 'Search',
        ],
    ]
);
```

`setAttrib` doesn't exists, but `setAttribute` does :

```
$element->setAttribute('placeholder', 'Search');
```

But in `FormText` view-helper, you can't add options anymore, so you have to do :

```
$element = $form->get('q');
$saved_placeholder = $element->getAttribute('placeholder'); // works even if not defined
$element->setAttribute('placeholder', 'Search');
echo $this->formText($element);
$element->setAttribute('placeholder', $saved_placeholder);
```

I know, this is an ugly hack !

Answer (score 0):

My solution using jQuery

```js
var elements = ['email', 'password', 'password_confirm'];
$j(elements).each(function(i, elem){
    $j('#' + elem).attr('placeholder', $j('#' + elem + '-label label').text());
    $j('#' + elem + '-label').hide();
    if ($j('#' + elem).hasClass('required-entry')) $j('#' + elem).attr('placeholder', $j('#' + elem).attr('placeholder') + ' *');
});
```