# Zend_Form Placeholder Translation

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, placeholder, zend-translate

I have a Zend application with a Zend_Form, which should use the HTML5 `placeholder` attribute instead of labels, [like done here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573282/placeholder-text-in-zend-text-element).

```
class Application_Form_Usereditprofile extends Zend_Form
{
     public function init()
     {
         [...]
         $this->addElement('text', 'FirstName', array(
            'filters'    => [...],
            'validators' => [...],
            'placeholder'=> 'user_editprofile_firstname', // string I want to translate
         ));
         [...]
     }
}
```

I initialized Zend_Translate so it should translate my forms by default. This works fine with labels. However, the placeholder gets used as it is, without being translated.

How can I translate the placeholder strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the the translate helper like this

```
'placeholder'=> $this->getView()->translate('user_editprofile_firstname),
```

btw. the `plceholder` attribute is not a substitution for the `label`.

From the [spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/common-input-element-attributes.html#attr-input-placeholder):

> The placeholder attribute should not be used as an alternative to a label.

Comment: Thanks that works! And placeholder instead of label is ok for me. I dont support outdated browsers. - I had waited for ages for this attribute, and now I'm not allowed to use???

Comment: Keep in mind that this will translate the 'placeholder' atrribute as is, future calls to setTranslator and/or translator changes will not affect the outcome. This might be considered breaking the abstraction of from the Zend\Form root.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my final solution. It translates all placeholders. Thanks to Jona for the answer.

```
foreach($this->getElements() as $key => $element)
{
    $placeholder = $element->getAttrib('placeholder');
    if(isset($placeholder))
    {
        $this->$key->setAttrib('placeholder',$this->getView()->translate($placeholder));
    }
}
```

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

Actually I like to have things automated, so I've simply made new My_Form class extending Zend_Form and replaced render method to handle things:

```
public function render(Zend_View_Interface $view = null)
{
        /**
         * Getting elements.
         */
        $elements = $this->getElements();

        foreach ($elements as $eachElement) {

            /**
             * Auto placeholder translation
             */
            if($eachElement->getAttrib('placeholder') !== NULL && $eachElement->getTranslator() !== NULL ) {
                $placeholderText = $eachElement->getAttrib('placeholder');
                $textTrans =  $eachElement->getTranslator()->translate( $placeholderText);
                $eachElement->setAttrib('placeholder', $textTrans);
            }

        }

    /**
     * Rendering.
     */

    return parent::render($view);
}
```