# PHP placeholders are not displaying until a refresh

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework2

I have a PHP form which is created using Zend Framework. I think I have added all the form placeholders correctly using constructor. But they are not showing in the browser until you refresh the page.
I have another form which is working fine(No need to refresh). I can't find what is the reason.

Placeholder example:

```
$this->add([
    'name' => 'name',
    'options' => [
        'label' => 'Name'
    ],
    'attributes' => [
        'placeholder' => 'Enter group name'
    ]
]);
```

Comment: try this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573282/placeholder-text-in-zend-text-element

Comment: Maybe will help attribute type? 'type'  => 'Text'